# Sharepoint export to Excel in mac

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

Currently I'm working on a Sharepoint 2013 project. What I want is to use export to excel out of the box but If i'm using mac then it does't allow me to export it. Is there any alternative way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

No: from [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/opal/2010/11/13/sharepoint-2010-on-a-mac-with-office-for-mac-2011/)

> *Since I have already installed Office for Mac 2011, can I use the features on the Ribbon such as Connect to Outlook, Excel, SharePoint Workspace, etc?*
>
> Unfortunately no. These features uses ActiveX controls except Export to Excel. And for Export to Excel feature, since Excel for Mac does not have a good support for Web Query(.iqy), it is really hard to make it to work.

Comment: Well this is a bad news for mac users!